# ionic2: how to use action sheet in ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

[image]

I want to make page as in image, I'm using Action sheet but I can't find resources to design action sheet like that, this is the code I used:

```
  sharePost() {
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
 title: 'Modify your album',
 buttons: [
   {
     text: 'Destructive',
     role: 'destructive',
     handler: () => {
       console.log('Destructive clicked');
     }
   },
   {
     text: 'Archive',
     handler: () => {
       console.log('Archive clicked');
     }
   },
   {
     text: 'Cancel',
     role: 'cancel',
     handler: () => {
       console.log('Cancel clicked');
     }
   }
 ]
 });

 actionSheet.present();

}
```

and this is the output image:
[image: the output actionsheet]

what should I do to customize my action sheet and If i shouldn't use action sheet what should I use?

Comment: did you tried using this plugin
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/

Comment: @amyogiji yes but I don't find where to make the desired design

Answer (score 1):

i believe you want to use share feature

actually it has nothing to do with design.

1st image only share the available apps to share from your platform.

**Now** to achieve this you need to use the below plugin

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/

and onclick call this instance member
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/#share

this is share anywhere link

so your code will be like

```
share(){
 this.socialSharing.share(message, subject, file, url).then(() => {
   // Sharing via email is possible
 }).catch(() => {
   // Sharing via email is not possible
});
}
```

Comment: yes, but about the design I used popover but I can't align it to bottom and I don't know which component I should use

Comment: i did'nt understand where popover come here in picture .

Comment: what I understand from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/ that how to share data but there is no design I want to make as the design in the image

Comment: as far as i know you , this is native functionality and you cannot modify the design. but if you come up with something, do let me know in this thread

Comment: and you cannot modify the design ?? which design

Answer (score 1):

what you try to achieve is may be **bottom-sheet.**

**Action-sheets** are native so we can't change their design.

but here are some workarounds.
check these examples,

codepen.io/jabas06/pen/vOMxjK

forum.ionicframework.com/t/an-alternative-to-md-bottom-sheet-in-ionic-2/93957/2

(links are plain text because of reputation  )

[ionic market plugin](https://market.ionic.io/plugins/bottom-sheets)

Comment: I'm a beginner in ionic2, I see in the page only these three files: file.html, file.scss and file.ts I didn't use  this sturucture before https://codepen.io/jabas06/pen/vOMxjK so how can I implement it in ionic2?

Comment: example is in ionic-1 put UI in file.html and javascript(js) logic in ts file.ts,syntax may be different.

Comment: @Al-shimaaAdel upvote or mark as answer if this helps you.thanks.

Comment: thank you it helps me I'm trying to use it in ionic2 updvote done